# Flutter, how to create border with text embedded?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Does anyone know how to create a border with text at the top like the following where is says "Create an account?

[image: flu]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 200,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 204, 255), width: 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      left: 50,
      top: 12,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Text(
          'Create an account',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: How to actually chop the border? This one does not work in transparent backgrounds.

Comment: @sh_ark You can make it container color as same as your background color or transparent

Comment: I've made container color as transparent as well, but it's showing border line in the background. Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: If there is a background color not transparent you can make it container color the same as the background.  For more, I have to update the code with new logic.

Comment: As I mentioned in first comment, I've a tranparent background.

Comment: this does not work for me the border is cutting through the text

Comment: Oh i see the container of the text has to be the same color as the scaffold background. Easy to achieve with ``Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor``

Comment: This doesn't work if you have an image or color gradient as an app background. Any other ideas?

Comment: but when put TextField , its doesnt show , could you make more example with input widget ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's an Out-of-the-box widget to do so, but you can use a workaround, I have two suggestions here, but you may need to take care of the fixed measurements:

[image]

**1- To use Stack/Positioned. here's the code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  // To be sure that Scaffold Background & text background always the same.
  Color backgroundColor = Colors.white;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 300,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black26)),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 5.0,
              left: 30.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 8.0,
                      ),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: backgroundColor,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'مرحباً',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black45,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**2- Another way is to set the Title as the first element in the Content(Column or what ever) then use ~negative padding to pull it up to cross the line using:**

```
// Negative padding
transform: Matrix4.translationValues(5.0, -14.0, 0.0),
```

here's an example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  Color backgroundColor = Colors.white;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 400,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              decoration:
                BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black26),),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    // Negative padding
                    transform: Matrix4.translationValues(5.0, -14.0, 0.0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 8.0,
                    ),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: backgroundColor,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'مرحباً',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black45,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jehad, both great suggestions. I just want' sure if there was an "out-of-the-box" type solution,

Comment: You are welcome, and yeah true, I haven't seen any native widget doing so..

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack(
children: <Widget>[
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
  ),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: DefaultTextStyle(
    style: const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    child: Text(
      'Watch lesson',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        fontFamily: 'Fredoka',
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
Positioned(
  left: 30,
  top: 3,
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: DefaultTextStyle(
      style: const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none),
      child: Text(
        'Coming soon...',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontFamily: 'Fredoka',
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
 ),
],
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a couple of answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the material package, there is already a built-in solution. For example if you are designing a form and want one of the text fields to have the style you mentioned, you can do something like this for the text field:

```
TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Last Name",
    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(), // <-- This is the key
    labelText: "Last Name",
  ),
  validator: _FormValidators.validateName,
),
```

Emulator screenshot:

[image]

#### Sources:

https://flutter-examples.com/create-text-input-textfield-widget-in-flutter/

Comment: This only works around a text field, not other widgets.